# Import error: cannot import name <class>

Tags: python, python-2.7

Cannot get my head around this ImportError. So I have the following structure:

- World:

  - World:

    - __init__.py
    - Europe:

      - __init__.py
      - file1.py
      - file2.py

file2.py has 4 classes, "Germany", "France", "Italy", "Spain". Contents of file1.py has the following import:

```
from World.Europe.file2 import Germany, France, Italy, Spain
```

However, this results in the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<path>/file1.py", line 1, in <module> .  
    from World.Europe.file2 import Germany, France, Italy, Spain  
ImportError: cannot import name Spain
```

Any clues why I'm facing an import error for only 1 of the 4 classes?

Comment: since it's in the same directory, use `from .file2 import *`

Comment: That results in the Traceback:
    ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package.
Also, that still doesn't answer the question why the import for the first 3 classes but not the 4th one.

Comment: How do you know it's for only one of the four classes?  What order does it perform the imports?  The fact that you get only one name in the error message doesn't mean the other three were successful.

Comment: Well, when I separated the imports of the 4th class, i.e. a separate import line "from World.Europe.file2 import Spain", it failed only on this line with the same traceback.

Comment: Then the problem must be in file2.  There is no way that Python treats the name "Spain" differently from the others.

Comment: Yeah, you are going to have to provide more details.

Comment: I imagine one of a couple of things are happening: you have a spelling error (Spain is spelled wrong in file2.py), you have an import loop (file1.py is trying to import from file2.py, and vice-versa), or the file2.py that's being picked up is actually on a different path.  It would help to show some contents for file1.py and file2.py that [helps reproduce the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).